# Efficiently zero out all but largest n elements for each image pixel

Tags: python, numpy

So I have an image I of size (H x W x C), where C is some number of channels. The challenge is to obtain a new image J, again of size (H x W x C), in which J[i, j] contains only the maximum n entries in I[i, j].

Equivalently, think about iterating through each image pixel in I and zero-ing out all but the highest n entries.

What I've tried:

```
# NOTE: bone_weight_matrix is a matrix of size (256 x 256 x 43)
argsort_four = np.argsort(bone_weight_matrix, axis=2)[:, :, -4:]

# For each pixel, retain only the top four influencing bone weights 
    proc_matrix = np.zeros(bone_weight_matrix.shape)

    for i in range(bone_weight_matrix.shape[0]):
        for j in range(bone_weight_matrix.shape[1]):
                proc_matrix[i, j, argsort_four[i, j]] = bone_weight_matrix[i, j, argsort_four[i, j]]

    return proc_matrix
```

Problem is this method seems to be super slow and doesn't feel very pythonic. Any advice would be great.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Generic case : Keeping largest or smallest `n` elements along an axis

Basically two steps would be involved :

- Get those `n` indices to be kept along the specified axis with [`np.argparition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html).
- Initialize a zeros array and use those earlier obtained indices with [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to select from the input array as well as assign into the zeros array.

Let's try to solve for a generic problem that works to select `n` elements along the specified axis and also be able to keep largest `n` as well as smallest `n` elements.

The implementation would look like this -

```
def keep(ar, n, axis=-1, order='largest'):
    axis = np.core.multiarray.normalize_axis_index(axis, ar.ndim)
    slice_l = [slice(None, None, None)]*ar.ndim

    if order=='largest':
        slice_l[axis] = slice(-n,None,None)
        idx = np.argpartition(ar, kth=-n, axis=axis)[slice_l]
    elif order=='smallest':
        slice_l[axis] = slice(None,n,None)
        idx = np.argpartition(ar, kth=n, axis=axis)[slice_l]
    else:
        raise Exception('Invalid order value')

    grid = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, ar.shape))]
    grid[axis] = idx
    out = np.zeros_like(ar)
    out[grid] = ar[grid]
    return out
```

**Sample runs**

Input array :

```
In [208]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: I = np.random.randint(11,99,(2,2,6))

In [209]: I
Out[209]: 
array([[[55, 58, 75, 78, 78, 20],
        [94, 32, 47, 98, 81, 23]],

       [[69, 76, 50, 98, 57, 92],
        [48, 36, 88, 83, 20, 31]]])
```

Keep largest `2` elements along last axis :

```
In [210]: keep(I, n=2, axis=-1, order='largest')
Out[210]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0, 78, 78,  0],
        [94,  0,  0, 98,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0, 98,  0, 92],
        [ 0,  0, 88, 83,  0,  0]]])
```

Keep largest `1` element along first axis :

```
In [211]: keep(I, n=1, axis=1, order='largest')
Out[211]: 
array([[[ 0, 58, 75,  0,  0,  0],
        [94,  0,  0, 98, 81, 23]],

       [[69, 76,  0, 98, 57, 92],
        [ 0,  0, 88,  0,  0,  0]]])
```

Keep smallest `2` elements along last axis :

```
In [212]: keep(I, n=2, axis=-1, order='smallest')
Out[212]: 
array([[[55,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20],
        [ 0, 32,  0,  0,  0, 23]],

       [[ 0,  0, 50,  0, 57,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 20, 31]]])
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The "all_idx = ..." line in both solutions was the bit I was missing. It seems an odd syntax for me, to build an array out of 3 with commas separating them. It does work - I've just reproduced it. Please could you explain this line a little further?

Comment: @BenjaminBiggs That would be a long discussion. Follow the link to `advanced-indexing` as linked in the post for a detailed one.

Comment: No worries, I see what you are doing. You are building a tuple with which to index the array I. I've seen this pattern before with np.where(.). Neat solution, and cheers for your help - I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminBiggs Yup, that `all_idx` is basically an indexing tuple, used for assigning as well selecting with `out` and `I` respectively.